# Searching for items in a JSON array Using Node (preferably without iteration)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Currently I get back a JSON response like this...

```
{items:[
  {itemId:1,isRight:0},
  {itemId:2,isRight:1},
  {itemId:3,isRight:0}
]}
```

I want to perform something like this (pseudo code)

```
var arrayFound = obj.items.Find({isRight:1})
```

This would then return

```
[{itemId:2,isRight:1}]
```

I know I can do this with a for each loop, however, I am trying to avoid this. This is currently server side on a Node.JS app.

Comment: Unless you have more info, iteration is unavoidable. But why are you trying to exclude that anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by "*without iteration*"? How could that work?

Comment: I suppose I meant without the tradition itteration pattern (a regular for each loop) But I am sure the is some creative use of regex and/or mapping that could be used as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var arrayFound = obj.items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.isRight == 1;
});
```

Of course you could also write a function to find items by an object literal as a condition:

```
Array.prototype.myFind = function(obj) {
    return this.filter(function(item) {
        for (var prop in obj)
            if (!(prop in item) || obj[prop] !== item[prop])
                 return false;
        return true;
    });
};
// then use:
var arrayFound = obj.items.myFind({isRight:1});
```

Both functions make use of the [native `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/filter) on Arrays.

Comment: The fun thing is that it still uses iteration. I don't get the OP's intention.

Answer (score 3):

Since Node implements the EcmaScript 5 specification, you can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `obj.items`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://underscorejs.org
This is an awesome library.

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Answer (score 2):

edited to use native method

```
var arrayFound = obj.items.filter(function() { 
    return this.isRight == 1; 
});
```

Comment: It is unlikely that he uses jQuery in Node.js, and even if it would be available one should use the native filter method.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The native filter method slipped my mind

Answer (score 2):

You could try find the expected result is using the [find function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you can see the result in the following script:

```js
var jsonItems = {items:[
  {itemId:1,isRight:0},
  {itemId:2,isRight:1},
  {itemId:3,isRight:0}
]}

var rta =  jsonItems.items.find(
   (it) => {
     return it.isRight === 1;
   }
);

  
console.log("RTA: " + JSON.stringify(rta));

// RTA: {"itemId":2,"isRight":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found an even easier way if you are using mongoDB to persist you documents...

```
findDocumentsByJSON = function(json, db,docType,callback) {
  this.getCollection(db,docType,function(error, collection) {
    if( error ) callback(error)
    else {
      collection.find(json).toArray(function(error, results) {
        if( error ) callback(error)
        else
          callback(null, results)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

You can then pass {isRight:1} to the method and return an array ONLY of the objects, allowing me to push the heavy lifting off to the capable mongo.